# What happens when all contact point in data-center goes down in cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, distributed-system

Cassandra cluster of 12 nodes (dc1: 4,dc2: 4,dc3: 4).

Added 4 (dc1) cassadra node's ip in ContactPoint.

what is the behaviour if all node in contactpoint goes down [(i.e) dc1 is down]

```
keyspace = {NetworkTopology : replication-factor : {dc1:2,dc2:2,dc3:2}}
```

In this case QUORUM satisfies 
2+2+2 = 6 replicas

QUORUM = (6/2)+1 = 4
dc2 dc3 are alive hence QUORUM is satisfied

Comment: In my case, it throws NoHostAvailable Exception no host queried.

Comment: Have you checked all the nodes connected internally or gossiping internally ? Nodetool utility is working after creating cluster?

Comment: If you mentioned only DC1's nodes as contact points in the driver and if all the nodes which are mentioned in the contact points are down then when you try to make new connection to the database since the nodes are down it won't be able to connect to cluster.